# Why does is my onchange event triggered when my page loads instead of when I click my radio button?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dom-events, onchange

I have the following code in my Javascript.  I'd like the alert to happen when a user checks the radio button, but instead it happens when the page loads, and NOTHING happens when the radio button gets checked. Why?

```
var myRadioButton = document.getElementById("myRadioButton");
myRadioButton.onchange=alert("Checked!");
```

The radio button starts off unchecked.  In the HTML it looks like this:

```
<div class="myRadioButton"><input type="radio" id="myRadioButton" name="radioButtons"  />&nbsp; This is my radio button 
</div>
```

Why on earth would the Javascript think an `onchange` event has occurred when the page loads? And why doesn't it recognize a change when I actually check the radio button?

In fact, whatever element I use with `onchange` makes the alert pop up when the page loads, without any user interaction at all.  Am I misunderstanding how `onchange` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you mean to do is

```
myradiobutton.onchange = function() { alert('Checked'); };
```

What you did will **execute** the `alert`-function and assign the *return value* of that function as an event handler to the `onchange` event (which will do nothing when executed)

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks! I'm a complete noob.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<script>
    var myRadioButton = document.getElementById("myRadioButton");

    myRadioButton.onchange = function () { alert("Checked!") };
</script>
```

Comment: Nice, yet the important bit is to wrap this code in a **document.ready** event handler

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
myradiobutton.onchange = alert('Checked')
```

You actually called alert function, and assigned its return value as event handler.